# Add a peramater to type alias

Tags: typescript, function, type-alias

I am using a function from a library whose type is

```
type QueryFetcher = (query: string, variables?: Record<string, any>) => Promise<QueryResponse> | QueryResponse;
```

and I would like to add a an additional argument to this type with out editing the type declaration in the source file.

I thought I could do something like

```
type WithHeader = (header: string) => Promise<QueryResponse> | QueryResponse

type QueryFetcherWithHeader = QueryFetcher & WithHeader
```

and that would yield

```
(query: string, variables?: Record<string, any>, header: string) => Promise<QueryResponse> | QueryResponse;
```

But it doesn't

Obviously, I dont understand something here, but I cant find something

Comment: `QueryFetcher & WithHeader` would have to be a function usable as both a `QueryFetcher` and as a `WithHeader`. Meaning you could call it like `f("query", {variable: ""})` and you could call it like `f("header")`.  Neither of those is the signature you want.  Appending to a parameter list programmatically is not really possible (especially with optional parameters), at least without not being a lot worse than just writing the intended `QueryFetcherWithHeader`'s signature by hand.  With more details of the use case I might suggest something better but right now I don't know what else to suggest.

Comment: The `&` is a intersection operator, but it doesn’t work with function the way you image. Why don’t you `import QueryResponse` just declare the function signature manually.

Answer (score 0):

Intersection type doesn't work on functions. Why don't you can create your own type as below.

```
type QueryFetcher = (query: string, variables?: Record<string, any>) => Promise<QueryResponse> | QueryResponse;

type QueryFetcherWithHeader = (query: string, variables?: Record<string, any>, header: string) => Promise<QueryResponse> | QueryResponse;
```